# How do I serve static files for my node-js server which are in my application root directory

Tags: node.js, express

Using    **app.use(express.static('public'))**  serves the files located under public folder

But if my files are outside the public folder in my application root directly how to serve them.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to serve files in a **folder** outside of the current working directory, `'./../<dir_name>'` is the way to go.

If you want to serve **individual files** instead of a directory, then you can use either,

```
app.use("/<some_url>", express.static(__dirname + '<path_to_file>'));
```

or

```
res.sendFile('<path_to_file>');
```

or use a simple library like, https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect-static-file.

I recommend the first approach though.

Note: replace the `<text>` with your file names and path names as required.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `./../` to go the parent of the current folder. If you have the following structure:

```
project
-   public
-   app_folder
--     app.js
```

You can use `'./../public'` as the static folder.